# Calculating a linear map using a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let: $T:\mathcal M_{2\times2 }(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R^3$ be a linear map that has the following transformation matrix in relation to the following bases.
>
> [image: pic]
>   Calculate $T\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 3& 4\end{pmatrix}$ and find $X\in \mathcal M_{2\times2 }(\mathbb R)$ such that: $T(X)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\\3\end{pmatrix}$

I'm not sure on how to use the transformation matrix in order to calculate the $T$.

Any directions please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You should express the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 3& 4\end{pmatrix}$ in the basis $\mathfrak F$ so assume that its  components in this basis is 
$$X=\begin{pmatrix} x \\y  \\z\\ t\end{pmatrix}$$
so solve the system of equations $A=xu_1+yu_2+zu_3+tu_4$ for $x,y,z$ and $t$ and then calculate:

$$TA=TX$$

Comment: Why we need to find the variables with the basis to get to $A$ in order to find it's linear map ? And why we don't use the transformation matrix ?

Comment: We can not apply a matrix of $T$ which $3\times 4$ on a matrix $2\times 2$, the number of columns of $T$ must be equal to the number of rows of $X$ in the product $TX$.

Comment: I see. So then I get a $4\times 1 $ matrix $X$ that still isn't what I was asked to calculate right ? Now I can multiply it by the transformation matrix and the product is what I was asked to find.

Comment: Yes you got it.

Comment: I got the second part also. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane 'Yes you got it', no,it's wrong. The product $TX$ yields the coefficients of the linear combination of the image with respect to $\mathfrak B$, that is, if $TX=[a\,b\,c]^T$, then $T(A)=a\vec{v_1}+b\vec{v_2}+c\vec{v_3}$.

Comment: @GitGud Yes the result is a vector in the basis $\mathfrak B$ so what's the problem?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane The OP asked you if $TX$ is what he was asked to find. The answer to this question isn't yes.

Comment: @GitGud No I didn't understand this, I left the second part of the question to the OP and he said that he got this second part.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I think with the second part he meant finding the preimage of $[1\,2\,3]^T$.

Comment: @GitGud My answer is just for the first part and the vector $X$ which I used is for the matrix $A$ not the vector $X$: the preimage of the second part. Right?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Forget the preimage. Regarding the first part of the question, the OP asked you if $TX$ is the final answer to the first part of the question (I think). And you said yes, which is not so.

Comment: @GitGud Of course yes! the matrix $T$ is $[T]_{\mathfrak B}^{\mathfrak F}$ which means that $TX$ is vector with components in the basis $\mathfrak B$ and this is the requested.

Comment: @gitgud what's wrong with it?

Comment: @GinKin See my first comment to see what I think is the correct answer.